# when install "Laravel Ecommerce Theme and CMS Admin Panel" it give me 404

Tags: php, laravel

I bought this theme 
https://codecanyon.net/item/laravel-ecommerce-universal-ecommercestore-full-website-with-themes-and-advanced-cmsadmin-panel/22334657

I followed this documentation
https://themes-coder.com/help-center/laravel-ecommerce-laravel-setup/
After extracting the theme admin source code to my host and open http://example.com/public/install in browser I have this response 404 | not found. 
and when I try to run composer install I also get this issue

> Source path ”./packages/rehantariq/laravel-installer” is not found for package rehan/laravel-installer

theme use Laravel 6

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: latest update of theme fix it.